# Paging Large Queries: total number

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, gocql

Regarding Cassandra and paging. I might guess the answer but just to be sure;

I know how to ask for a pagesize, but is it possible to get the eventually total number for a query. Like you query `select * from tableName` with a pagesize of 10, but if you did not use paging you would get 100. Is it possible to get the number 100 when using pagesize 10?

Note: Just if it is of any use, I am using `gocql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain answer is no, getting number 100 in your example means knowing the result of "SELECT count(*) FROM table", which is a perf killer query.

The best thing you can get is an **estimate** of number of partitions per node using **nodetool** or calling directly **JMX Beans**. But it won't get you the estimate of **CQL row** (because in 1 partition there may be N rows if your table has clustering columns)